# Python: How much space does each element of a list take?

Tags: python, memory, list, performance

I need a very large list, and am trying to figure out how big I can make it so that it still fits in 1-2GB of RAM. I am using the CPython implementation, on 64 bit (x86_64).

*Edit: thanks to bua's answer, I have filled in some of the more concrete answers.*

What is the space (memory) usage of (in bytes):

- the list itself

  - `sys.getsizeof([]) == 72`
- each list entry (not including the data)

  - `sys.getsizeof([0, 1, 2, 3]) == 104`, so 8 bytes overhead per entry.
- the data if it is an integer

  - `sys.getsizeof(2**62) == 24` (but varies according to integer size)
  - `sys.getsizeof(2**63) == 40`
  - `sys.getsizeof(2**128) == 48`
  - `sys.getsizeof(2**256) == 66`
- the data if it is an object (`sizeof(Pyobject)` I guess))

  - `sys.getsizeof(C()) == 72` (C is an empty user-space object)

If you can share more general data about the observed sizes, that would be great. For example:

- Are there special cases (I think immutable values might be shared, so maybe a list of bools doesn't take any extra space for the data)?
- Perhaps small lists take X bytes overhead but large lists take Y bytes overhead?

Comment: you might want to answer your own question with the information you added, however it's pretty obvious that bua has answered the main part of your question, and EOL has provided a way to predict more accurately and fit more items into RAM.

Comment: This was posted as an answer which had to be removed as a Link Only Answer, but it seems like it might be useful, so I'm posting it as a comment. Python Module of the Week did an article on Python Memory Management, which you can view here: http://pymotw.com/2/sys/limits.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

point to start:

```
>>> import sys
>>> a=list()
>>> type(a)
<type 'list'>
>>> sys.getsizeof(a)
36
>>> b=1
>>> type(b)
<type 'int'>
>>> sys.getsizeof(b)
12
```

and from python help:

```
>>> help(sys.getsizeof)
Help on built-in function getsizeof in module sys:

getsizeof(...)
    getsizeof(object, default) -> int

    Return the size of object in bytes.
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want lists of numerical values, the standard [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) module provides optimized arrays (that have an append method).

The non-standard, but commonly used [NumPy](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html) module gives you fixed-size efficient arrays.